# SQL inner join - performance improvement

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, correlated-subquery, sqlperformance

I have the following SQL but wish to improve the performance (Option 2 below currently takes about 24 seconds).

**EXPLAIN MySQL** - using example in answer below[image]

**Option 1 - basic select (very slow)**

```
select f.name, f.flowid, m.traceid, m.traceday, m.logtimestamp
from flow f, messageinfo m 
where traceid = (select max(traceid) from messageinfo where flowid = f.flowid)
```

**UPDATE**

**Option 2 - with inner join (faster but still too slow)**

```
select m.traceid, f.name, f.flowid, m.traceday, m.logtimestamp
from flow f
  inner join messageinfo m 
  on m.flowid = f.flowid
  where traceid = (select max(traceid) from messageinfo where flowid = 
  f.flowid)
order by f.name
```

I need to loop through the flow records (there are approx 900) and for each flow select the related flow in the messageinfo table that is the most recent, i.e. has the highest traceid for that particular flow.  Both SQL examples above work but would like to see if I can improve performance for Option 2 if possible.  The final result should be a best effort and only return a traceid where a related flow record can be found (like an inner join).
Can anyone suggest a more performant way?  Bear in mind I would like to return the data from both tables in the final result (as shown with example above).

I need to also emphasize I don't have the freedom to modify the DB with new/updated indexes.  So mainly looking for improvements to SQL without DB modifications.

That said, it is still beneficial noting any index improvements for future work.

Comment: Sounds like a groupwise-max problem:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to rewrite your query as using join, Move your dependent sub query part to sub clause and join this with your main query.

```
select m.traceid, f.name, f.flowid, m.traceday, m.logtimestamp
from flow f
inner join messageinfo m on m.flowid = f.flowid
inner join (
    select flowid, max(traceid) traceid
    from messageinfo 
    group by flowid
) m1 on  m.flowid = m1.flowid and m.traceid = m1.traceid
order by f.name
```

Also add composite index on (flowid,traceid)

Comment: Ran query above few times and this is getting 11 seconds average time, which is fastest so far.  Many thanks! :)

Comment: @user1746582 Can you include EXPLAIN plan for this query in your question

Comment: that's done, ran EXPLAIN against your suggested query above with snippet pic the result.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that EXPLAIN does not say "Using index for group-by" for the derived table.  What is the definition of the FlowID index?

Answer (score 0):

As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always the EXPLAIN for the given query.

That said, and while were waiting for the necessary information to appear, in my experience an uncorrelated subquery can sometimes outperform a correlated one, so I'd be tempted to try writing the query this way:

```
select m.traceid
     , f.name
     , f.flowid
     , m.traceday
     , m.logtimestamp
  from flow f
  join messageinfo m 
    on m.flowid = f.flowid
  Join
     ( select flowid
            , max(traceid) traceid 
         from messageinfo 
        Group
           By flowid
     ) x
    On x.flowid = f.flowid
   And x.traceid = m.traceid
 order 
    by f.name
```

Comment: Thanks I ran your query and got this result: " Error: Unknown column 'f.traceid' in 'on clause' "

Comment: Well, that's easy enough to fix!!

Comment: Yeah I know, thought you'd want to clean up your answer ;-p

Comment: I ran again few times with correction and time is almost consistently identical to M Khalid Junaid's answer, i.e. within a second difference (Khalid's is slightly faster but only just).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine -- although you should write it using qualified column names *for all columns*:

```
select m.traceid, f.name, f.flowid, m.traceday, m.logtimestamp
from flow f inner join
     messageinfo m 
     on m.flowid = f.flowid
where m.traceid = (select max(m2.traceid) from messageinfo m2 where m2.flowid = m.flowid)
order by f.name;
```

You need indexes on `messageinfo(flowid, traceid)`.  An index on `flow(name, flowid)` might also help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a window function like:
max(traceid) over(partition by traceid order by traceid)
from messageinfo

?

Answer (score -1):

You can use SQL index to retrieve your data fast. You cannot see the indexes, they are just used to speed up searches/queries. Below is the syntax given to add the index.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```